# Does displacement current exist in a DC circuit with a capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, capacitance

Displacement current is there in the AC circuit with a Capacitor. Does it exist in a DC circuit with a Capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't (at least theoretically). It depends on your definition of DC. Let's define the Voltage at the capacitor $ V_1 $ as

$$ V_1(t) = 3~\mathrm{V} $$

which would be a DC-Voltage. The displacement current is related to the change of the electrical field or the change of voltage across the capacitor respectively. The voltage never changes and never has changed. Therefore the displacement current is always zero.

In DC-circuit analysis it is in general possible to just leave out capacitors for calculations (whereas inductors can typically be shorted). They only change the dynamic behaviour of the circuit but not the DC behaviour.

---

Looking at it from a more realistic point of view: Each DC-Voltage has to be turned on and eventually turned off. In these cases you have transients which create a change in voltage and therefore displacement current.

Comment: What do you mean by "but [does] not [change] the DC behaviour" ?

Comment: For a DC analysis of a circuit you can just ignore all cpacitors in the circuit. At DC (frequency = 0) all capacitors have an infinitely high impedance, and therefore, no impact on the circuit

Comment: I might just not understand what you mean, but I think I really disagree. Comparing a DC circuit with a capacitor to one without a capacitor: the circuit with no capacitor will light bulbs continuously, while the circuit with a capacitor will light bulbs only for a split second (depending on the capacitance) during charging or discharging. This seems like a capacitor impacts the circuit. If we're only interested in the limiting behavior of the circuit, then I think I agree with you.

Comment: As I've mentioned: It depends on your definition of DC and AC. You wrote it will light for a split second. There you have it. This is not DC. It changes therefore it has to be considered as a function of time.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. But that will happen even if we use a battery to supply voltage for the circuit. So that's an odd definition of AC current, to me.

Comment: If you use a battery and a capacitor in parallel to power a light: For calculation of DC levels (DC -Voltage and DC- Current) you can leave out the capacitor. It has no effect. Its impedance is infinite. Only for frequencies unequal to zero a capacitor has an effect. The thing is: Powering a light with only a capacitor is considered to be a DC circuit. However the current and voltage waveforms contain higher frequencies. To calculate something like this you have to solve differential equations. This can be done for example using the Laplace transform.

Answer (score 0):

MOMENTARILY it exist. WHEN capacitor is getting charged [transition state]due to increase in accumulated charge displacement current flows between the plates
FOR a AC source displacement current always flows and is not momentarily